# SpriteKit physics body returning to original vertical position after hit/knock

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, physics, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to make a physics mechanic where a vertically standing object can be hit or knocked down and then will pivot back up to it's origin position. Think of it like a floor mounted punch bag. So the object will have a low pivot/anchor point.

I just wanted a little theoretical direction in how to approach this using SpriteKit physics.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use a SKPhysicsJointPin and modify frictionTorque depending on which side the body sways

Comment: The object cannot be permanently anchored or joined to the 'ground' object. I was maybe thinking joining a 'high mass' at the bottom and 'low mass' at the top, hopefully the the 'low mass' object will defy gravity somewhat but will not be able to lift the 'high mass' object up

Comment: If design is the issue the question would be a better fit for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com You can probably achieve the effect by applying force/torque to the body, the behavior doesn't necessarily have to be modelled exclusively with bodies and joints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates a composite object by joining two bodies: a circle and a weight. The weight is offset relative to the center of the circle and is much denser. When added to the scene, gravity rotates the combined object so the side with the weight is on the bottom. To use it 1) create a new sprite kit game, 2) replace the default initWithSize and touchesBegan methods with this code, and 3) run and click at various locations in the scene.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];
        circle.path =[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(-32, -32, 64, 64)].CGPath;
        circle.position = location;
        circle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:32];

        SKSpriteNode *weight = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(8, 8)];
        // Adjust this to get the desire effect
        weight.position = CGPointMake(location.x+1, location.y+28);
        weight.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:4];
        // Adjust this to get the desired effect
        weight.physicsBody.density = 100.0;

        // The physics bodies must be in the scene before adding the joint
        [self addChild:circle];
        [self addChild:weight];

        // Join the circle and the weight with a physics joint
        SKPhysicsJoint *joint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:circle.physicsBody bodyB:weight.physicsBody anchor:weight.position];
        [self.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
    }
}
```